# IceFaces and FileResource - delete after session expires

Tags: icefaces

I'm using [Icefaces](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/). I generate reports for users and provide it using **FileResource** class. I do nothing with the file, since it should be available for download whenever user clicks on link to resource.

However, after user logs out, the report is no longer needed and should be deleted. Is there a **build-in** option in IceFaces to bind FileResource with session and automatically delete it when session expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resource** binds to a file which already exists when you are binding it to a Resource. It is expected that the file would be needed again, so there is probably no point in providing a method to delete the file.

The IceFaces tutorial on FileUpload talks about manually deleting files after session expiry **using a session listener**. So I guess IceFaces does not provide any method to delete files, whether or not they are binded to a Resource.